# Caching problems on SO site today?

Tags: support, caching

I am not able to make my code look like a code, it looks like a code in preview but then again resets to normal lines when i click on edit, e.g. I add my code to "code sample {}" but it shows wrong when i edit it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159726/datacontract-is-not-visible-in-returned-soap-xml

In preview it looks fine..

### Fixed itself now :S

**Edit**

Seems like site isn't refreshing itself like before, I must have to refresh page to see the change, pretty sure it worked before..

Comment: Could be caching by your browser.

Comment: It looks fine (well the number of spaces is inconsistent but it still formats as code).

Comment: @Stijn could be but I didn't cleared cache to fix it, and it never happened before :/

Comment: I have noticed caching problems on SO today as well, it might be related. For example: clicking on a post title does not refresh the page, even though it pretends to do so.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: See [Browser caching has become a bit too aggressive](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237600), should be cleared now.

Comment: Voting to reopen, as cache headers *did* change. Although Chrome *should* have been caching before, it apparently wasn't doing so correctly. Not that it *does* cache (up to 60 seconds), the change is surprising people.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there was a caching problem in that the [Cache-Control header was updated to prevent public proxies from caching logged-in pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237626).

However, since the new header did not include a `max-age` parameter anymore browsers started caching responses too aggressively. That omission was [corrected earlier today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237624).

In addition, it appears that the `Vary` header has been changed from `*` to `Accept-Encoding`; if so then Chrome did not cache anything before (as it could not determine variants to cache) while now it'll adjust the cache based on wether or not compression was requested.

In other words, yes, there was a problem, and it is now fixed. Pages are now correctly cached by your browser; the `max-age` parameter is still set to 60; your browser will cache pages up to 60 seconds. Clicking a title returns a cached page; explicitly reload (<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>) if you are impatient.

*Update*: caching has changed again and many pages now have `Cache-Control: no-cache` set, tuning off caching altogether. Tag pages now use `private`, with no `max-age` set.

Comment: Thank You, reloading using "F5" works too

Comment: Hmmm, I'm still having caching issues that only reloading the page is fixing. This is annoying.

Comment: @j08691: because Chrome, for some reason, was not caching before even though the previous cache-control header `public, max-age=60` *told it to*. All that changed is that the header is now `private, max-age=60`, meaning only browsers can cache, not public proxies too. Ergo, Chrome appeared to have a bug in the cache control handling.

Comment: So for example when I add a comment to a question, then edit it, it's now normal for me to not see the edit unless I force a browser refresh?

Comment: @j08691: Looks like it. I remember seeing that `Vary` was set to `*` before, which would have prevented Chrome from caching. It is now set to `Accept-Encoding`, letting Chrome cache correctly.

Comment: That seems like a huge step backwards in terms of usability. Either I sit and wait for a minute so that the cache expires, or I manually force a reload? I can see where this will lead a to a lot of crossed and missed messages.

Comment: @j08691: Comment links (from notifications) do include a query string which makes the page look 'unique' and the browser will fetch a new copy in that case. So at least in that respect comments give you a way out. But I agree that caching could be improved still; using ETags for example. I've pitched that to Marc already.

Comment: @j08691: Actually, in Chrome at least a simple reload is also enough.

Comment: True, but still an extra step (and a step backwards).

Comment: Pages used to update in Firefox: such as when I answer, or view a personal reply and the red icon would disappear, and now they don't.  I'm not into HTML techniques or web browser low level stuff - in simple terms why was this changed?  It has reduced the SO site usability markedly.  I would have to press F5 or control R hundreds of times a day.

Comment: @foxidrive: if your inbox counter doesn't go away, that'd be a *different* problem. Caching has changed again but to make pages **not** cached in the browser.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Appreciate your reply.  I'll run some tests.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If I answer a question and then use the browser back button, that question used to re-appear at the top of the list in the page.  I just started Firefox 31.0 in safe mode to test this and when I use the back button the page doesn't change.  Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @foxidrive: that was *always* the case; going back with the browser button shows a cached copy, regardless.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm certain the page updated, or I'm in a parallel universe.  I never had to reload the page - it just worked.  As above the red inbox counter for your reply doesn't go away on a back button - that used to go away too.

Comment: @foxidrive: let me put it this way: in *Chrome* it never used to go away on going back. The back-button does not trigger an update on that counter. That's normal behaviour. You'll find this applies to many more things on Stack Exchange; the back button can easily result in stale data being shown. Edited a post and navigated away? The back button will then show you the page as it was before the edit, etc. That's because changes made via AJAX are *not* part of the browser cache.